# Selecting all with a length of less than 8 characters, and not null, and not empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How would I selecting all of the values which are less than 8 characters in length, and not a null value and not an empty value?

This is what I have but it is still pulling in null values

```
select distinct
alphaidx, 
case when len(termdatex)<8 then termdatex end as termdatex
from table
where termdatex is not null and termdatex!=''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in your `case` expression. Implicitly, anything not handled in one of the `when` clauses is returned as `null`. Here, since you don't filter them out in the `where` clause, any string with 8 or more characters will be returned as `null` from the `case` expression. To fix this, you could move all your logic to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT alphaidx, termdatex
FROM   some_table
WHERE  termdatex IS NOT NULL AND termdatex != '' AND LEN(termdatex) < 8
```

Comment: simple error that i made... thank you for the answer.